# Insert Into doesn't work with no errors

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

I wrote a code for an article system but my `INSERT INTO` doesn't work and after 2 hours of looking at it I can't find the error. Error reporting is turned but I don't get any errors besides it doesn't save to database. Anyone an idea?

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO n_news 
  (article_title,article_title_clean,article_cover_img,article_cover_thumb,article_text,
  article_yt_id,article_yt_loc,article_cat,article_published,article_user,acticle_review,article_active,article_draft) 
  VALUES  
  (:article_title,:article_title_clean,:article_cover_img,:article_cover_thumb,:article_text,
  :article_yt_id,:article_yt_loc,:article_cat,:article_published,:article_user,:article_review,:article_active,:article_draft)";
$q = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':article_title'=>$article_title,
                ':article_title_clean'=>$article_title_clean,
                ':article_cover_img'=>$article_cover_img,
                ':article_cover_thumb'=>$article_cover_thumb,
                ':article_text'=>$article_content,
                ':article_yt_id'=>$article_yt_id,
                ':article_yt_loc'=>$article_yt_loc,
                ':article_cat'=>$_POST['article_category'],
                ':article_published'=>$article_publish,
                ':article_user'=>$user_id,
                ':article_review'=>$article_review,
                ':article_active'=>$article_active,
                ':article_draft'=>$article_draft));
```

Comment: What mode is PDO(if that's what you're using) running in? If it's on defaults, then your prepare and/or execute call will return a boolean FALSE to signify failure. You're not testing any return values for failure, or using a try/catch block, you're basically just assuming nothing could ever fail.

Comment: It's PDO, and I know but I'm assuming it's a code error.

Comment: Are you checking for errors? If not, add `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Used the try catch but with your method I successfully found my typo! Big thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: You're very much welcome Bart, cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Did you have seen the permission (006, 777, etc) of database's file (*.frm in MySQL)?